# How to find all files ending with .rb with Linux?

Tags: linux

I am in a directory which contains more directories.
What command can I use to get all files ending with `.rb`?

Comment: For future reference, these types of questions belong here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You could try

```
find . -type f -name \*.rb
```

Comment: What's the difference from `find . -type f -name *.rb`?

Comment: If you don't escape the ’*’ the shell will try to match the pattern and doesn't pass it to 'find'. Therefore this will only work If the files reside within the current working directory.

Answer (score 16):

Try this `find . -type f -name '*.rb'`.

For a more thorough explanation, get the 'Unix Power Tools' book.

Comment: wouldn't that also find files without a dot in front of the `rb`? The OP was very specific, so I think your answer should be too :)

Answer (score 5):

This should help:

```
find . | grep *\.rb
```

Comment: Sorry, overlooked. Reverted. I was taken aback by using 'pipe grep' in case when all needed functionality already built-in inside `find`.

Comment: Thank you! I should judge my actions more carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the files ending with .rb by following command

```
find . -type f -name '*.rb'
```

To store the results after finding, you can use the following command

```
filesEndingWithRb=$(find . -type f -name '*.rb')
```

To print the results

```
echo $filesEndingWithRb
```